# Why a function with no arguments works, but a function with void as argument doesn't?

Tags: c, function, arguments, parameter-passing, void

In the below codes I am calculating `PI` with a function external to `main()`. The only difference between the two is:

- **1st code.** I am not passing any arguments: `void calculate_pi ();`
- **2nd code.** I am explicitly saying there are no arguments to pass: `calculate_pi (void);`.

I would have thought the second one is better, but doesn't seem to be the case. Why is this? Thank you!

**1st Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void calculate_pi ();

int main(void)
{

    calculate_pi ();

    return 0;
}

void calculate_pi ()
{
    int i, signo;
    double pi_approx = 1, pi_final;

    for (i = 1; i < 1000000; ++i)
        {
            signo = (i%2) ? -1 : 1;
            pi_approx = pi_approx + (float) signo / (2*i+1);
        }

    pi_final = pi_approx * 4;
    printf("%.10f\n", pi_final);
}
```

**2nd Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void calculate_pi (void);

int main(void)
{

    calculate_pi (void);

    return 0;
}

void calculate_pi (void)
{
    int i, signo;
    double pi_approx = 1, pi_final;

    for (i = 1; i < 1000000; ++i)
        {
            signo = (i%2) ? -1 : 1;
            pi_approx = pi_approx + (float) signo / (2*i+1);
        }

    pi_final = pi_approx * 4;
    printf("%.10f\n", pi_final);
}
```

Comment: `the second one is better` Does the second one compile and work? `I am explicitly saying there are no arguments to pass` No, you are not, `void` doesn't mean that in a _function call_. It means that in a _function declaration_.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer @KamilCuk I added below the correct code based on your comment! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring a function with an empty parameter list, as in `void calculate_pi();`, is an old C syntax that did not specify the parameter types. It should be avoided in new code. Preferably, functions are declared with parameter lists, such as `int foo(char *x);`. The new syntax provides better type information and allows compiles to check argument types and provide useful warning and error messages.

Because C used `()` to declare functions without a specification of parameter types, a different syntax was needed to specify that a function had **no** parameters. Using `(void)` was adopted as a special case to indicate this, per C 2018 6.7.6.3 10:

> The special case of an unnamed parameter of type `void` as the only item in the list specifies that the function has no parameters.

Thus, declaring `void calculate_pi(void);` does not say that `calculate_pi` accepts a `void` parameter; it says that `calculate_pi` does not have any parameters. This is the preferred way to declare a function that has no parameters.

Since the function accepts no parameters, it should be called with no parameters, using `calculate_pi()`.

`calculate_pi(void)` is not a valid C expression. A function argument must be a value, but `void` is a type, and the type `void` cannot appear as a function argument. So the preferred code in modern C is to declare the function to take no arguments:

```
void calculate_pi(void);
```

and call it with no arguments:

```
calculate_pi();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the use of `void` as parameter type at the declaration/definition of a function and as argument at an actual call to a function.

`void` can in this context only be used as parameter, but not as argument in a function call. An expression of type `void` shall not be used in anyway because it in fact yields no value at all. Else the program invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

> "The (nonexistent) value of a void expression (an expression that has type void) shall not be used in anyway, and implicit or explicit conversions (except to void) shall not be applied to such an expression. If an expression of any other type is evaluated as a void expression, its value or designator is discarded. (A void expression is evaluated for its side effects.)"
>
> Source: C18, 6.3.2.2/1

You need to call `calculate_pi` as `calculate_pi()` and not as `calculate_pi(void)`:

```
int main (void)
{
    calculate_pi();

    return 0;
}
```

---

> "*I would have thought the second one is better, but doesn't seem to be the case.*"

It is indeed better to use `void` at the declaration/definition instead of to use an empty parameter list, because a declaration with an empty parameter list is strictly seen not a prototype.

The C standard states (emphasize mine):

> "For each different entity that an identifier designates, the identifier is visible (i.e., can be used) only within a region of program text called itsscope. Different entities designated by the same identifier either have different scopes, or are in different name spaces. There are four kinds of scopes: function,file, block, and function prototype. (**A function prototype is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters**.)"

Thus, some compilers can give a warning, if you specify a empty parameter list, like f.e. Clang does:

> "*warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]*"

But in this case, the issue lays somewhere else, as explained above.

---

Side Note:

- A compiler will usually throw an error if you provide `void` as argument by default, so your code shouldn't have even been compiled. Please consider to swap to an up-tp-date and standard-compliant compiler, like GCC or Clang.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to go with the first code because you already specified the return type of calculae_pi() function to void. It's not necessary to put a void as you did in the second code.

Answer (score -1):

Based on @KamilCuk comment, the correct code should be this then:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PI 3.14159265359

void calculate_pi (void);

int main(void)
{

    calculate_pi ();

    return 0;
}

void calculate_pi (void)
{
    int i, signo;
    double pi_approx = 1, pi_final;

    for (i = 1; i < 1000000; ++i)
        {
            signo = (i%2) ? -1 : 1;
            pi_approx = pi_approx + (float) signo / (2*i+1);
        }

    pi_final = pi_approx * 4;
    printf("%.10f\n", pi_final);
}
```

Comment: Answers should contain answers. Showing code without explanation is not an answer. Referring to a comment is not an answer; the explanation should be in the answer itself.